# SetTimeout infinite loop and run function once

Tags: reactjs, loops, setinterval

I need to reduce the amount of network calls from setInterval function. Every 3 seconds, API is called. The first API sometimes takes longer time to receive a response from the server.

**Code**

```
useEffect(() => {
 const id = setInterval(async () => {
  console.log('hello')
  await callAPI()
  console.log('bye')
 }, 3000);
 return () => {
  clearInterval(id);
 };
})
```

> Problem

The setInterval function calls the callAPI method every 3 seconds while the first call API method still running waiting for server response which results in many API calls which are spamming server.

> Expected

SetInterval function should wait for the first method called's response, before running method again every 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use a `setTimeout` that calls itself:

```
useEffect(async () => {
 let id;
 const api = async () => {
    console.log('hello')
    await callAPI()
    console.log('bye')
    id = setTimeout(api, 3000);
 });
 await api();
 return () => {
  clearTimeout(id);
 };
})
```

For example:

```js
const api = () => {
    console.log('hi');
    setTimeout(api, 1000);
    console.log('bye');
}

api();
```

```js
    const Example = props => {
      const [countdown, setCountdown] = React.useState(100);
      React.useEffect(() => {
          const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
              setCountdown(countdown - 1);
          }, 1000);
          return () => {
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          }
      }, [countdown]);
      
      return (<div>{countdown}</div>)
    }


    // Render it
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Example />,
      document.getElementById("react")
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.13.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.13.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

    <div id="react"/>
```

Comment: I need to infinite loop the function every 3 seconds... setTimeout only called once..

Comment: you're not understanding what I mean, if in the timeout function you do another setTimeout, it will run every 3 seconds, I posted an example

Comment: Turns out it works on the example you given, but inside UseEffect doesn't work.

Comment: see snippet, setTimeout works just fine in useEffect